# Binding inside a NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstablecellview

I'm using a NSOutlineView view based and i want to bind a NSSlider and a NSTextfield to a NSDictionary key (@""duration"). The dictionary is a property of my NSTableCellView subclass. I'm facing an error when trying to setup the binding :

The error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSApplication 0x100506400> addObserver:<NSTextValueBinder 0x102609a90> forKeyPath:@"info.duration" options:0 context:0x10260c820] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "info" property.'
```

***.h:***

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ObjectFileTableCellView : NSTableCellView {
    NSTextField *_textFieldFilePath;
    NSTextField *_textFieldDesription;
    NSButton *_checkBox;
    NSDictionary* _info;

    NSSlider*  _slider;
    NSTextField* _labelStartTime;
}


@property(retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *textFieldFilePath;
@property(retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *textFieldDescription;
@property(retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *labelStartTime;
@property(retain) IBOutlet NSSlider *slider;
@property(retain) IBOutlet NSButton *checkBox;

@property(retain) NSDictionary* info;

@end
```

***.m :***

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item{
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Files"]) {

        if ([item isKindOfClass:[OMN_Object class]])
        {
```

//DONE
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item{
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Files"]) {

```
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[OMN_Object class]])
    {
        OMN_Object *o = item;

        ObjectFileTableCellView *v = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"FileCell" owner:self]; // File'S owner


                hide = NO;
                NSString* d = [o.fileInfoDetails valueForKey:@"duration"];
                [v.slider setMinValue:0];
                [v.slider setMaxValue:[d doubleValue]];

                NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", v.slider.doubleValue];
                [v.labelStartTime setStringValue:val];
                [o.fileInfoDetails setValue:val forKey:@"startTime"];
                v.info = o.fileInfoDetails;

    ...
```

***My NSOutlineView view:***

[image: NSTableColumn]

***NSTableColumn:***

[image: Last]

***NSTextField Binding Setup:***

[image: Binding Setup]
[image: Binding setup 2]

The wanted result :

[image: Jimi Hendrix]

How to setup the binding to get what i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Said before, File's Owner.info.duration Make no sense because File's Owner is kind off class outlineview. The dictionary Info is a property off ObjectFileTableCellView.

I bound programmatically the NSTextfield to info.duration and it work great !

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to bind `info.duration` to the cell itself, not the text field, assuming that "File's Owner" is indeed your `ObjectFileTableCellView`.

Use `labelStartTime` as the controller key when you configure the binding.

Double-check your bindings configuration for the slider as well; you may have made a similar mistake.

Comment: See my edit : ObjectFileTableCellView *v = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"FileCell" owner:self]; // File'S owner

Comment: In your statement, the table view owns the cell view. That has nothing to do with the relationship between the cell view and the bindings between its info dictionary and its text field in Interface Builder.

Comment: Did you try doing what I told you in my answer?

Comment: Yes i tried but I can't modify the field controller key. What do you think about bind programmatically the textfield to FileCell.info.duration instead of File's Owner.info.duration with IB?

Comment: It's worth trying. But always remember your original error message: You're attempting to bind to something that's not KVC-compliant for your key path.

Comment: Will try this after the week-end. Any other suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: File's Owner.info.duration Make no sense because File's Owner is kind off class outlineview. The dictionary Info is a property off ObjectFileTableCellView. I'm right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.